# Can access to Google Analytics with historical data be recovered after losing administrator access?

Tags: google-analytics, security, data, administration, permissions

I have lost my administrative accessibility to my website under User Management in Google Analytics. I have discussed this with my webmaster, but he does not claim responsibility for it nor is he attempting to fix it.

How do I gain my administrative access to my account under User Management?

Also, I have somehow lost all my Google Analytics data over the years because of this. How do I retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in the pass, and was able to resolve it by contacting Google directly. Google sent me a specific file I had to update on the website to prove that I really owned it, then they granted me admin access to the account and I could recover previous data.

Comment: Where did you contact Google?  Is there a contact page for this?

Comment: From the Analytics help pages, you should find a contact form.